# How to run VPN through a university proxy?

Tags: vpn, proxy

I am at a university and we have to specify a proxy address and port to connect to the internet. Chrome and firefox also ask for a username and password every time I start them. I'd like to use a VPN (such as Betternet) here. The only VPN I have been able to run here is psiphon, but it is incredibly slow. Tor also works, but again, is also pretty slow. I can easily use VPNs at home. Is there any way I can connect through a VPN at university?

If it helps, my principal objective is to appear to websites that I am browsing from the United States.

Comment: Do you know if your university network de-prioritizes or blocks certain VPN traffic? Have you contacted your University technical support staff for assistance on this?

Comment: @music2myear I am almost certain that they will not do anything I request them to. I can run psiphon, and I think it's because I can enter my proxy address, port, username and password in it. So in my opinion, VPN access isn't blocked.

Comment: You do understand that TOR isn't a VPN, right?  What exactly is your question?  Your ability to connect to a VPN will entirely depend on the firewall configuration, which you have no control over, you will have to find a different VPN that works through trial and error.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I do understand that Tor isn't a VPN